# Copy AD attributes (state to city) in a specific OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, ou

I have a problem with a simple script. I need to copy attributes (STATE to CITY) on all users in my OU. I found this script, but there is an error somewhere.

Could someone help me with this?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "MY OU" -Properties city, state |
    ForEach-Object {
        Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName ` -Replace @{city=$($_.state)}
    }
```

Comment: *"but there is an error somewhere"* "Error" meaning what exactly? Are you getting an error? What does it say? Where does it occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command to grab all users where state has a value (a precaution to avoid attempting to use null values which Replace will not accept) and write that value into the city attribute (L)

```
PS> Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=test accounts,dc=domain,dc=ccTLD" -LDAPFilter '(st=*)' -Properties city, state |  Select-Object * |  ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName `  -Replace @{l=$($_.state)}}
```

Comment: Working. Thx LisaJ